# Need help on creating a variable inside a requests payload

Tags: python

This is the payload for a request on python:

```
  payload = "{\"depositCoin\":\"eth\",\"destinationCoin\":\"btc\"}"
```

I want to make the btc part variable, in other words, able to be changed depending on user input. I have tried replacing the string with a variable name but it doesn't work. I have also tried to replace it with a ***%d*** and then using ***% variable*** but it still does not work. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to dump your dictionary into the proper format.

```
import json

payload = {"depositCoin": "eth", "destinationCoin": None}

coin = input()
print(coin)
# 'lite'


payload["destinationCoin"] = coin

json.dumps(payload)
'{"depositCoin": "eth", "destinationCoin": "lite"}'
```

Comment: Think your `coint` should be `coin` and not sure what that `lite` is doing there :)

Comment: thanks for the typo, I was illustrating that _my_ input was lite but I can see how that might be confusing

Comment: Ahh... one way you could do that is `print(coin)` and then follow with a commented line such as: `# 'lite'`

Comment: The problem I am facing is that the format of payload is this:
"{\"depositCoin\":\"eth\",\"destinationCoin\":\"btc\"}"
instead of this:
{\"depositCoin\":\"eth\",\"destinationCoin\":\"btc\"}

Comment: @SneakyKiwi Which non-escaped is the same as the payload this answer provides... have you tried using the payload here - unless where you're sending it is particularly strange - it should just work.

Comment: ` for section in json_coins['data']:
        coinswitchdata.write(section['symbol'] + '\n')
        payload = "{\"depositCoin\":\"eth\",\"destinationCoin\":\"btc\"}"
        payload_dict = json.loads(payload)
        payload_dict["destinationCoin"] = section["symbol"]
`

This returns error 'Input Json invalid'